# How to verify a certain javascript function has been called during unit testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking

I'm using JsTestDriver and a bit of Jack (only when needed).  Does anyone know how to verify that a javascript function has been called during unit testing?

E.g.

```
function MainFunction()
{
    var someElement = ''; // or = some other type
    anotherFunction(someElement);
}
```

And in the test code:

```
Test.prototype.test_mainFunction()
{
    MainFunction();
    // TODO how to verify anotherFunction(someElement) (and its logic) has been called?
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JavaScript is very powerful language in terms that you can change the behaviour at runtime.
You can replace anotherFunction with your own during test and verify it has been called:

```
Test.prototype.test_mainFunction()
{   
    // Arrange 
    var hasBeenCalled = false;
    var old = anotherFunction;
    anotherFunction = function() {
       old();
       hasBeenCalled = true;
    };

    // Act
    MainFunction();

    // Assert (with JsUnit)
    assertEquals("Should be called", true, hasBeenCalled);

    // TearDown
    anotherFunction = old;
}
```

**The note**: You should be aware that this test modifies the global function and if it will fail it may not always restore it.
You'd probably better pick [JsMock](http://jsmock.sourceforge.net/examples/) for that.
But in order to use it you need to separate the functions and put them into objects, so you ***would not have any global data*** at all.

Comment: Great answer. I believe there are some JavaScript aspect oriented programming (AOP) libraries to help do this.