# How to test a function has been called inside another function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs, sinon

I have a form. When the user goes from step 1 to step 2, the code checks all required fields in step 1 before moving the user to step 2. When the user is on step 2, 3 or 4 and hits refresh or opens the url in a new window, they are redirected to the intro page.

My problem is testing the code and what to test.

I am using React, Redux, Jest and Sinon.

```html
// actions.js

export const redirectToIntroPage = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const fields = {
    field1: getState().app.inputs.field1,
    field2: getState().app.inputs.field2,
    field3: getState().app.inputs.field3,
  };

  if (objHasNullValue(fields)) {
    goToPage(PAGES.INTRODUCTION);
  }
};
```

`getState()` is called several times because I only care about the specified keys. `app` has a whole bunch of other stuff I don't need.

```html
// parsing.js

export const objHasNullValue = obj => {
  for (var property in obj) {
    if (isNull(obj[property]) === true) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
};
```

`goToPage` is self explanatory.

```html
// action.test.js

  describe('redirect to intro page', () => {
    let sandbox, fakeDispatch, fakeState, goToPage;

    const fakeGetState = () => (fakeState);

    beforeEach(() => {
      sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
      fakeDispatch = sandbox.stub();
      goToPage = sandbox.spy();
    });

    afterEach(() => {
      sandbox.restore();
    });

    it('should redirect if the Personalisation Form has a null value', () => {
      fakeState = {
        app: {
          inputs: {
            field1: null,
            field2: null,
            field3: null,
          },
        },
      };
      redirectToIntroPage()(fakeDispatch, fakeGetState);
      expect(goToPage.calledOnce).toBe(true);
    });

    it('shouldn\'t redirect if the Personalisation Form is complete', () => {

    });
  });
```

My thinking for the tests is to stub out the `goToPage` and check it has been called. I have to call `redirectToIntroPage()(fakeDispatch, fakeGetState)` in order to do so, but how do I get inside `redirectToIntroPage` to check `goToPage` has been called?

I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787107/how-to-verify-a-certain-javascript-function-has-been-called-during-unit-testing) which makes sense conceptually but how do I translate this in Sinon and Jest?

I also looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47287942/how-i-can-i-unit-test-that-a-function-inside-another-function-was-called) which is the same idea.

Answer (score 0):

Get `goToPage` from arguments not from outer scope (as it hard to mock).
Split your function into 2:

```
// Use for testing
export const redirectTo = (goToPage) => () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const fields = {
    field1: getState().app.inputs.field1,
    field2: getState().app.inputs.field2,
    field3: getState().app.inputs.field3,
  };

  if (objHasNullValue(fields)) {
    goToPage(PAGES.INTRODUCTION);
  }
};

// Use as before
export const redirectToIntroPage = redirectTo(goToPage);
```